# Elasticsearch: copying entities from one index to another

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to copy entities from one index to another within elasticsearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [my blog](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/05/20/reindex-elasticsearch-with-logstash/) where I described how to do that with logstash.

Comment: Am specifically looking to use elasticsearch, not logstash. The issue with logstash is that the file input plugin has no concept of terminating processing at EOF, so we do not know when to delete a file. The alternative is to use stdin plugin and to pass the filename as a parameter to logstash. But then logstash has no notion of file processing and, in the case of a crash, will not know where it was up to. One idea: use logstash stdin to write to temporary index, and, within elasticsearch, move entities to perm index. Do you have a better solution? Thanks!

Comment: Did you read my blog? I never talked about file input plugin, did I?

Comment: And BTW you can not do that today with elasticsearch only.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. The blog is great. Are you able to help on the question of how to configure the logstash elasticsearch input plugin to either 1) move\rename a file once it has processed it or 2) for logstash to terminate on completion of processing the file. Any help or advice you can give on this is greatly appreciated. If it cannot be done, what other strategies do you recommend  for moving\archiving files once logstash has finished with them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install NodeJs and NPM
2. open terminal or cmd and type: npm install elasticdump
3. cd into the elasticdump/bin file (node_modules/elasticdump/bin)

   ./elasticdump \
     --input=http://10.11.12.13:9200/sourceIndex \
     --output=http://192.168.1.2:9200/destinationIndex \
     --type=data

ElasticDump for Linux:

```
yum install epel-release

yum install nodejs

yum install nodejs npm

npm install elasticdump

cd node_modules/elasticdump/bin

./elasticdump \
  --input=http://192.168.1.1:9200/source \
  --output=http://192.168.1.2:9200/destination \
  --type=data
```